# Text Search in a field of a BSON Object using mongodb and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, full-text-search, bson

I have rails app with a model `Follower`, with fields `user_id`, `users_followed` and `user_details`. `user_details` is stored as a BSON Object. `user_details` has a field `description`, which has a text value. Like:

```
user_details={..., 
              description: "description about the user",
              ...}
```

I want to be able to do a text search inside this `description` field. How should I index it?

**Edit: updated the model**

Here is the model:

```
class CommonFollowerUser
  include Mongoid::PrefixableCommonFollowerUserDocument

  field :user_name, type: String, default: ""
  field :user_details, type: BSON::ObjectId


  belongs_to :keyword, inverse_of: :CommonFollowerUsers


  # index({ "user_details['description']" => 1 }) ##doesnt work
  # index({ "commonfolloweruser.user_details" => "text" }) ##doesnt work
  # index({ "commonfolloweruser.user_details['description']" => "text" }) ##doesnt work


  freeze_stack! # this needs to be the last line in a prefixable model

end
```

Edit:

The data collection and storage is being done by this code:

```
try:
    user_details = TwitterAPI.get_details(
    rand_api_key,
    search_phrase,
    paginate_newer_attribute,
    paginate_older_attribute,
    search_for_id = False)

    for user in user_details:
        db_twitter_common_followers_user_details.update({
                'user_name': str(search_phrase)},
                {'$set' :{'user_details' : user,
                        'network' : 'twitter',
                        'keyword_id':str(keyword_id)
                        }
                    },upsert =True)

    except Exception, e:
        print "Error: %s" % e
```

You see, the json returned by twitter is being dumped into the `user_details` field. `user_details` does not refer to any other `User` model.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

Comment: Since the field here is referenced and not embedded the index defintion would be made on the "User" model, which is presumably where the "details" field lives. But understand as a "referenced" design, your text search queries must be made on the "User" model and not on this present model that only references the key from the other data.

Comment: The field is not referencing to any other User model. Wait let me show you how I am collecting the data. Editing the post.

Comment: The point is MongoDB only works with a single collection at a time. Any illusion of something else happening is purely performed in the client. So what is the class definition for `db_twitter_common_followers_user_details`? That is where you define the index and that will be what you use to query.

Comment: ``db_twitter_common_followers_user_details`` is a collection based on a model with the name ``CommonFollowerUser``. It has 2 attributes, ``user name: string``, and ``user_details: BSON::ObjectId``. Yes, indexing in this model makes sense. But the bigger problem still remains, how should I index it? ``index "user_details['description']" => "text"``, doesn't work, so I am guessing its not the right way.

Comment: Which is exactly why you are being asked to show the exact model definition for this and basically what you have tried.

Comment: Not sure why you are still not understanding this. A BSON `ObjectId` is something like this: `ObjectId("55bcbbc0408c74e7d57c0177")`. A "hash" is more like this `{ "description" => "something here" }`. So if you have `ObjectId` then that only points to data somewhere else. The "ObjectId" itself does not contain that data. Your model only contains the `ObjectId` and not the data as a "Hash". It needs the data as a hash in order to index it. Otherwise that "referenced" data is in another collection, with a another model, and that model is where you put the index and do the query from.